# Normalize wave function and check if it is in Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics

> Consider a particle of mass m freely propagating within the box x ∈
>   [0, R]. Prepare the particle in the state corresponding to the wave
>   function
>
> $  \psi (x) Asin(\frac{3\pi x}{2R}) cos(\frac{\pi x}{2R}) $
>
> inside the box, and vanishing outside. – Show that the state
>   corresponding to ψ(x) belongs to the Hilbert space of the system.
>
> – Determine a complex number A such that the state is normalised
>
> – How many different energy-eigenstates are contained in the state
>   corresponding to ψ(x)? What are the energies which one can therefore
>   measure when the system is in the state corresponding to ψ(x)?

Am not sure how to proceed with part 1 and part 3, so if abyone can show me how to?

Also for part 2,

I think i do this

$\int_{0}^{R} | \psi|^{2} dx = 1 $

$|A|^{2} \int_{0}^{R}sin^{2}(\frac{3\pi x}{2R}) cos^{2}(\frac{\pi x}{2R})$

using this identity $ sin\theta + sin\phi = 2sin(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2})cos(\frac{\theta-\phi}{2})$

I get

$<x| \psi> = \frac{A}{2}[sin(\frac{\pi x}{R}) + sin(\frac{2 \pi x}{R})]$

how to proceed from here to normalise ? Also if anyone can show me how to do the first and last part of the question.

thank you very much,

Comment: 1) Show that the function $\Psi = A\sin(\frac{3\pi x}{2R}) \cos(\frac{\pi x}{2R}) $ is normalizable and satisfies boundary conditions. 3) The eigenstates are $\psi_n=\sqrt \frac{2}{L} \sin \left(\frac{n\pi x}{R}\right)$. Two know which states are  present in $\Psi$, calculate $<\psi_n|\Psi>$.

Comment: not sure how to show its in hilbert space,  $ \frac{A}{2} \sqrt{\frac{R}{2}}[\psi_{1}(x) + \psi_{2}(x)] $